# Inno Setup - how to show a transparent PNG Image?

Tags: inno-setup

I want to show it on the welcome page.

How is that possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the newsgroup posting at http://news.jrsoftware.org/news/innosetup.code/msg23217.html, PNGs are not supported on Setup Forms and would also be unsupported on the Welcome Page.

Comment: Inno Setup now supports transparent BMPs at least. See the [answer by @RobeN](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34518746/850848).

Answer (score 7):

In 5.5.7 update (28th December 2015) there was 32bit BMP with Alpha Channel function implemented.

> The WizardImageFile and `WizardSmallImageFile` `[Setup]` section directives now support 32 bit bitmap files with an alpha channel. Use the new `WizardImageAlphaFormat` `[Setup]` section directive to specify if the bitmap file has its red, green and blue channel values premultiplied with the alpha channel value or not. Contributed by [Honza Rameš](https://github.com/shadow-cs) via [GitHub](https://github.com/jrsoftware).

and

> Pascal Scripting changes:
>    Class `TBitmapImage` now supports 32 bit bitmap files with an alpha channel. Make sure to set the `Bitmap.AlphaFormat` property before loading the bitmap file.

http://www.jrsoftware.org/files/is5-whatsnew.htm

Answer (score 6):

However, there is a workaround if your intention is mainly to show a partially transparent image:

the `ReplaceColor` and `ReplaceWithColor` properties of the `TBitmapImage` class allow replacing a color in the image with another color dynamically. The trick is to replace a "dummy" color (e.g. magenta) with the background color of the wizzard:

- Convert the png to bmp (this will remove the alpha channel)
- Replace the parts of the image which should be transparent with a color which doesn't occur in the rest of the image (e.g. magenta: `#FF00FF`)
- Include the image in your ISS:

  ```
  [Files]
  Source: "my\transparent\image.bmp"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: dontcopy
  ```
- Add the image to the wizzard page:

  ```
  [Code]

  procedure InitializeWizard;
  var
      ImageFile: String;
      Image: TBitmapImage;
  begin
      ImageFile := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\image.bmp');
      ExtractTemporaryFile('image.bmp');
      Image := TBitmapImage.Create(WizardForm);
      with Image do
      begin
          Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ImageFile);
          Parent := WizardForm.WelcomePage;
          Left := 10;
          Top := 10;
          Width := 30;
          Height := 30;
          ReplaceColor := $00FF00FF;                        // Replace magenta...
          ReplaceWithColor := WizardForm.WelcomePage.Color; // ...with the background color of the page
      end;
  end;
  ```

It is not as pretty as a real alpha transparency but should be fine for simple cases.